# Transfer function of OP Amp circuit system?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, transfer-function, circuits

I have this circuit here, and I'm fairly certain the function I have is correct but I just wanted to be sure. I am also a little thrown off from the resistor connected to the + of the op amp. The function I came up with is:

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{R_2C_2s}{(R_1C_1s+1)(R_2C_2s+1)}$$

[image]

Comment: Tip: The term "op-amp" is an abbreviation of "operational-amplifier". It doesn't get capitalised (except at the start of a sentence).

Comment: oh thank you for the tip!

Comment: Welcome to EE StackExchange. Making your post easily readable will help get good responses.  Use [MathJax](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) to format equations nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of circuit can be generalized as

$$ \frac{V_o}{V_i}=-\frac{Z_f}{Z_i}$$

In your circuit, \$Z_f\$ is the parallel combination of the impedances in the feedback arm, and \$Z_i\$ is the parallel combination of the impedances in the input arm.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I broke it up when I solved. So my Zf=R2C2s and Zi=(R1C1s+1)(R2*C2s+1)
Not sure if it's right though considering the resistor at the bottom

Comment: The resistor at the bottom drops no significant voltage so V+ is at zero volts.  This is based on the [ideal op-amp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) assumptions, no current flows into V+ or V-.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

If I was to duplicate this circuit and connect it in series to this one (Vin and Vout would be moved properly of course), how would that change the transfer function?